# Laravel 5.4 Conditional setting controllers in router

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to bind controllers to routes on some condition.

I have path `/cabinet`. I need to bind it to a different contollers accordingly to user roles. For example, if user's role is `seller` then path `/cabinet` should be processed by `SellerController`.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'cabinet', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        if (Auth::user()->hasRole('seller'))) {
            Route::resource('/', 'SellerController');   
        }
        if (Auth::user()->hasRole('client')) {
            Route::resource('/', 'ClientController');
        }
    });
});
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will find some help in this [question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663764/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-laravel-5-4/663863#663863)